# How to store the results from a stored procedure into a temp table or a view in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a stored procedure in BQ where the results i want to be stored inside a temp table for further analysis.

How can we do it inside BQ?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary tables are session based, i.e. they only live within a `Begin` and an `End` block. Temp tables can be created inside a Stored procedure but are not accessible outside it.

You can create a temp table using following syntax - [Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement)

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE <ANALYTICS_TABLE> ...
```

You can use this Temp Table throughout the procedure to perform Data transformations, cleansing etc.

Temp tables are recommended when you have multiple transformations which refer to a common Transformation, which can be saved as a Temp table for intermediate use.
[image]
Consider Transformation 1 & Transformation 2 to be heavy operations. Transformation 3 & 4 both utilise common Transformation 2, Hence to avoid re-computations of Transformation 2, it's better to save it as a `temp table` to be referred multiple times.

But in order to save the results, you must save them to a Permanent Table in order to persist it. Permanent table then can be queries in other procedures and you can Create Views on top of them.